# Scroll position fixed element synchronously with non-fixed element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a header with a fixed position. And I also have content (items-wrapper) with a static position. If my header doesn't have a fixed position it scrolls normally with an items-wrapper container like it use to be when the page has overflow-x (synchronously). But I need to make items inside the fixed header synchronously scroll left and right with items in items-wrapper (and vice-versa). I add an event listener on the left and right container's scroll but it doesn't work well and it has no endpoint (I assume that scroll needs to stop when it reaches the end of the viewport like it behaves when header didn't have fixed position). How can I synchronize them ? And what endpoint of scroll it should be? Any help will be appreciated! Code example below

```js
const fixedHeader = $('.header');
const headerWrapper = $('.header__wrapper');
const scrolledItems = $('.items-wrapper');
let shift = 0;

const scrollArea = (scrollItem) => {
  scrollItem.on('DOMMouseScroll mousewheel', function (e) {
    if(e.originalEvent.detail > 0 || e.originalEvent.wheelDeltaX < 0) {
      shift = shift - 20;
      scrolledItems.css('transform', `translateX(${shift}px`);
      headerWrapper.css('transform', `translateX(${shift}px`);
    } else {
      shift = shift + 20;
      scrolledItems.css('transform', `translateX(${shift}px`);
      headerWrapper.css('transform', `translateX(${shift}px`);
      //scroll left
    }
    return false;
  });
}

scrollArea(headerWrapper);
scrollArea(scrolledItems);
```

```css
.container {
  border: 4px solid red;
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  padding: 20px;
}

.header {
  display: flex;
  background-color: green;
  width: 500px;
  height: 50px;
  overflow-x: auto;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 20px;
  right:0;
}

.header__wrapper {
   display: flex;
   width: 100%;
}

.header > .item {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  height: 200px;
  overflow-x: auto;
}

.items-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.item {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <header class="header">
      <div class="header__wrapper">
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
       </div>
    </header>
    <div class="items-wrapper">
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What you want is to move both scrolls at the same time of both containers?

Comment: @Julián yes, like overflow worked when fixed element didn't have fixed position

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm you can try this in you **JS Code**:

```
$('.header').scroll(function(){
    $('.wrapper').scrollLeft($(this).scrollLeft());    
    
    if ($('.header').scrollLeft() >= 270) {
        $('.wrapper').scrollLeft($('.wrapper').scrollLeft() + 50);
    }
})

$('.wrapper').scroll(function(){
    $('.header').scrollLeft($(this).scrollLeft()); 
})
```

**UPDATE 2:**

This update both cotainers (`header` and `wrapper`) have the same width and the horizontal scroll have the same height, then the condition in the `header` event scroll for determinate the scroll's end is not necesary:

**CSS:**

```
.container {
  border: 4px solid red;
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  padding: 20px;
}

.header {
  display: flex;
  background-color: green;
  width: 500px;
  height: 50px;
  overflow-x: auto;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 20px;
  right:0;
}

.header__wrapper {
   display: flex;
   width: 100%;
}

.header > .item {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.wrapper {
  display: block;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  padding: 10px;
  position: fixed;
  left: 20px;
  top: 90px;
}

.items-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  margin-right: 0px;
}

.item {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
```

**JS Code:**

```
$('.header').scroll(function(){
    $('.wrapper').scrollLeft($(this).scrollLeft());
})

$('.wrapper').scroll(function(){
    $('.header').scrollLeft($(this).scrollLeft()); 
})
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Can you please explain why did you choose 270 and 50 pixels range ?   I need to adaptive this also for mobile devices.

Comment: I put this condition in the header event, because the horizontal scroll of this one is much larger than that of the wrapper container, so 270 is the limit or is the value to know that the scroll has reached its top, when reaches this limit then the horizontal scroll of the other container has not reached its end and will move 50 more pixels to the right (it can be any other value, I put this value to test), however I have modified the CSS to make both containers have the same size and this condition is not necessary, you can check my update if you want.